# C++ compilation error: "cast from 'WCHAR*' to 'WORD' loses precision"

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw

MyGUI library.

There's a line in its sources:

```
mHandle = (size_t)::LoadCursor(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW));
```

*mHandle* is `size_t`

*LoadCursor* returns `HCURSOR`.

Error:

```
D:\Dev\MyGUI_3.2.0_RC1\Common\Input\Win32\ResourceW32Pointer.cpp:48: error: cast
from 'WCHAR*' to 'WORD' loses precision
```

Here's the full source:
[www.pastebin.com/gzqLBFh9](http://www.pastebin.com/gzqLBFh9)

MinGW compiler.

There was error `cast from 'CHAR*' to 'WORD' loses precision` and **selbie** gave an advice to add macro here: [Create window with WNDCLASSEX? [Cpp]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527736/create-window-with-wndclassx-cpp/5527812#5527812) . Thanks to him - it disappeared.

Comment: Why don't you declare `mHandle` to be of type `HCURSOR`? Why do you need to cast? And if you have to cast (I don't think you do need to), why are you using C casts? Your code is in C++.

Comment: It would be a good solution, if it was my code :) But by changing something in others library lots of errors from different parts of code appears :). But I'll do that if there wouldn't be any other ways.

Comment: If you can't change the code, then how can you fix the bug?!

Comment: Yes, that's quite logic. I thought it could be solved using some other magic macro or something like that :) - which are special for platform\OS\Compiler . Because thousands of people use this library and says it works Okay with MinGW too!

Comment: Is `ResourceW32Pointer.h` your code or is it 3rd party?

Comment: Now I'm just trying to build 3rd party library (MyGUI) binaries to use it in my project. Developers keep silence about this error, so I try to understand what went wrong and why it doesn't builds on my machine exactly :).

Comment: Is `ResourceW32Pointer.h` your code or is it 3rd party? Can we see it?

Comment: `ResourceW32Pointer.h` is part of this library. Here they are: http://nopaste.info/c37fef31eb.html

Comment: `size_t` is just wrong for `mHandle`. No two ways about it. @Mark is correct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is actually at `MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW)` and isn't related to the type of `mHandle`. [Aside: I agree that `mHandle` should not be `size_t` but I think that is not your current problem.]

Since `IDC_ARROW` is defined to be `MAKEINTRESOURCE(32512)`, the code should in fact read

```
LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW)
```

rather than

```
LoadCursor(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW))
```

The latter code fails because IDC_ARROW is `LPTSTR` but `MAKEINTRESOURCE()` expects `WORD`. That explains the error message you see.  In fact `IDC_ARROW` is already a resource type and needs no further processing.

Likewise, all the other calls to `LoadCursor()` are in error.

Comment: That's it. Now this part of library compiles well.. But there are lots of errors further. :) Anyway, it was quite interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`mHandle` should not be a `WORD` - this is completely wrong. A `WORD` is 16 bits, and a `size_t` is usually 32 or 64 bits depending on the compiler options, the same size as a pointer with the same options. Since 32 and 64 are both greater than 16, the compiler is complaining and rightly so.

It seems you have a definition of `size_t` that is incorrect, you should fix it. Then you should redefine `mHandle` so that it is truly a handle and not a `size_t`.

Comment: @MInner yes that is true, which is why I'm saying that there's an incorrect definition of `size_t` somewhere. Actually the much more important fix is to select the correct type for `mHandle`.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was little bit cut somehow. So, as far as Code::Blocks finds any declarations of size_t in this project, the only one is in stddef.h, so it must be okay. And about redefining of mHandle - it is used as size_t in may different places (code is not mine so ..), so it could be difficult to rewrite all the library. Trouble must be somewhere else?

Comment: @MInner, is it possible that your compiler options are set to do a 16-bit build? Seems unlikely in this age, but it's the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: @Mark I think it's all a red herring. See my answer and consider that `MAKEINTRESOURCE()` receives a `WORD`.