# C++ TEXT macro of TCHAR*

Tags: c++, winapi, macros, tchar

I am trying to create a TCHAR* variable by using

```
TCHAR* example = TEXT("example");
```

but it wont even compile and says: A value of type const wchar_t* cannot be used to initialize an entity of type TCHAR*.
What should I do?

Comment: consider just using `auto example = L"example";` unless you really need to support non-unicode Windows 95 installations

Comment: Unless you are supporting Windows 98, **STOP USING TCHAR** and just go all in with wide-string APIs on Windows.  Previous answers on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712101/104458) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50572941/104458) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56307155/104458) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5527812/104458)

Comment: Even if you are supporting Win9x, there's the [Microsoft Layer for Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Layer_for_Unicode). There's really *no* reason to avoid subscribing to the Unicode versions of the APIs today.

Comment: Or you could use the statement like:`TCHAR example[] = TEXT("example");` This will get a (7+1) size of `TCHAR` array and can be converted to `TCHAR *`(but must pay attention to the problem of array out of bounds).

Comment: Hi, @Mary, If there is an answer available to you, feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it or you could add your own answer and [accept yourself](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add `const`, because the `TEXT()` macro returns a pointer to a `const wchar_t`.

```
const TCHAR* example = TEXT("example");
```

If the assignment were allowed without the `const`, you would be able to modify the `const wchar_t` data through the pointer.

See also [A value of type "const char*" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759558/)

Comment: Note that macros don't return objects of any type. TEXT simply adds the wide string literal prefix conditionally. The string literal itself is const whether the macro is used or not.

Comment: Note, you can also use `LPCTSTR` instead of `const TCHAR*` directly: `LPCTSTR example = TEXT("example");`